# Merging png files to a csv as a column in R

Tags: r, csv, png

So I have a problem (that may or may not have a simpler solution than what I'm trying to do):

I have a csv:

`df <- read.csv('dfPhotos.csv')`

This csv includes an id column, each of which looks something like `id_860139460671021056`

I also have a group of png images matching the id for each row that look like `860139460671021056.png` for example (such that for every id, there exists an image.

I want to be able to merge the images to the original csv in a for loop such that the last column in the dataset is the png file matching the identifier.

Here's an example of the ID column and the NA's are where I want the images to be:
[image: data subset]

1. Is this possible?
2. If it's not, is there a simple alternative making them retrievable in R?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show few rows of your data and show expected output based on that?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I've edited my question to be more precise and added a snip of my dataset and where I expect my data to be.

Comment: It's not clear what you want in the `tweets.image` column. The file name of the image? The image itself, stored as a blob? Do you want to view the image? A link to the image?

Comment: I want the image itself there, although I'm not sure it's possible to save an image to a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add a new cokumn by getting the id from `tweet.id`column? We could remove `"id_"` part of the identifier and `paste` `".png"` at the end to do that.

```
df$tweets.image <- paste0(sub("id_", "", df$tweets.tweet_id), ".png")
#OR also
#df$tweets.image <- paste0(sub("id_(.*)", "\\1", df$tweets.tweet_id), ".png")
```